# android GPRS detection network?

Tags: android, android-networking, gprs, network-state

sorry for my question is perhpas stupid, but actually i'm newer to the world of android (work with xamarin android and android studio => a little).

I work on an APP who must to connect to network (mobile / wifi ).

I would like to understand the GPRS signal and for this i have some knowledge about it BUT NOT not sure about my experience ..

It's better to confirm with some stackOverFlow expert :)

1- for me , GPRS is the network mobile (2g, 3g, lte, ..) ?
2- the device detect AUTOMATICALLY this GPRS signal ?
3- For detecting this GPRS signal, we just need to add a SIM card into a device ?
4- a device CAN'T connect in several network (GPRS and wifi) ?
5- if some network(gprs and wifi) are available, the device will connect to the better network automatically ?

Thanks for your time and all your knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html).

This is to determine if you have connection:

```
ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                      activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

and this is to verify if you're on WiFi:

```
boolean isWiFi = activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
```

Comment: Hello lucas thanks for your response that's great ..but could you confirm my knowledge about my five questions ? i'm confuse with all these signal

Comment: Yes, GPRS is the mobile network (3G, LTE, 4G, etc..). NetworkInfo with getType() determines whenever you're on WiFi or Mobile Data. Yes, you need a SIM card with available network. A device can actually connect to several network because there are some devices which accept 2 SIM. No, it won't. I will connect to WiFi if it is present, even if 4G may be stronger. Select my response as the correct one if it covers all your doubts please

Comment: Hello lucas nicoletti => thanks you so much that's great and sorry for stupid question ! you know i'm new to mobile and i use my phone just for to send sms , receive call that's all ...i know i know i'm old perhpas :) i have validate your post thanks you see you later guy

Comment: No problem dude! We're here to help!